# Confusion around ACTIVITY_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION on Android 10 when granted permission still throwing exception

Tags: android

I'm confused over an exception thrown in my app trying to use `ACTIVITY_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`. I'm testing on a Pixel 4a with Android 10, targeting API 29 in my `build.gradle`

I do get prompted for the permission on first run and grant it. I step through in the debugger and see the permission is granted, yet it throws the exception when I try to do so.

The exception:

```
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mycompany.mypackage.MyActivity, PID: 24473
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.mypackage/com.mycompany.mypackage.MyActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a00699b -- permission denied for window type 2002
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a00699b -- permission denied for window type 2002
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:955)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:387)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.mycompany.mypackage.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:98)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
09-02 11:36:23.734 24473 24473 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
```

In my manifest I am declaring

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

In my activity I am checking for permission in `onCreate` and attempting to add my View to the window manager:

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView=null;
    private WindowManager windowManager=null;
    private boolean mViewAddedToTop=false;

    final static int DRAW_ON_TOP_REQUEST_CODE = 105;

    private boolean canDrawOnTop() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(this);
        } else {
            return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),     Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }
    }

    void askPermissions() {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (!android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, DRAW_ON_TOP_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        } else {
                // if we haven't been granted draw on top then request it
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),     Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},
                            DRAW_ON_TOP_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String url=b.getString("url");
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    });

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    mWebView.clearCache(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    if (canDrawOnTop()) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        //
        // crashes here
        //
        windowManager.addView(mWebView, params);
        mViewAddedToTop=true;
    } else {
        askPermissions();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mViewAddedToTop) {
        if (mWebView != null) windowManager.removeView(mWebView);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
        if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) && requestCode == DRAW_ON_TOP_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // attach the view to the window manager
                windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

                params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                params.x = 0;
                params.y = 100;

                    windowManager.addView(mWebView, params);
                    mViewAddedToTop = true;


                } else {

                    // permission denied
                    Log.i("foo", "user declined to grant SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION) and I'm at a loss. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not allowed to add overlay of `TYPE_PHONE`. Use [`TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY).

Comment: Good gosh....@Pawel turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!